# amplify push not working as more tables are added

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have an Amplify project with a GraphQL API Schema comprised of 28 @model's. After adding an additional @model and running amplify push, The Amplify CLI (v5.3) returns...

```
Uploading files...
```

...for several minutes. It then returns:

```
Uploading files...× An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
An error occurred during the push operation: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.
```

The additional model being added is simple with no secondary indices or connections to any other model. I have been working with this project for several weeks without having a problem with any amplify push updates.

I tried the following:

1. Running amplify pull, making the change, and then running amplify push
2. Creating a new amplify project.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to approach this?

EDIT

When I exclude the additional model, it takes about 14 seconds for the CLI to complete uploading the files. But when adding just a single additional model, it takes several minutes.

Comment: It's disheartening that @AWS support apparently doesn't GAF about this